# What's the difference between starting jar manually and by Runtime.getRuntime().exec?

Tags: java, jar, runtime, exec

It seems that the same java jar might consume vastly different amount of processor resources when started manually by `java -jar` and when started via `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)`.

When started by `java -jar` it consumes basically nothing, but when started by another program via `Runtime` the processor consumption goes into double digits and I don't understand the difference in behavior.

To reproduce the problem I have a class with a for-loop that does nothing and waits when Enter will be pressed.

```
public class Cycle {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        System.out.println("Entering cycle...");
        for (char c = (char) in.read(); ; c = (char) in.read()) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                System.out.println("Enter was pressed. Exiting...");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I pack it into a jar and use another java program to start it.

```
public class StartApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar <path to jar>");
    }
}
```

And that's when magic starts happening. Processor consumption sky rockets as if there is an infinite loop like `while(true)` inside the `Cycle` class. I can fix that by adding `Thread.sleep(100)` inside for-loop and then processor consumption goes back to normal, but the question is not about that.

Can someone advise me what is conceptually different between running the jar manually and getting expected behavior in terms of consumption and running it via `Runtime`?

Comment: My guess is the process has no associated input stream when started via `Runtime#exec`, thus the `read()` method continuously returns `-1`.

Comment: The method `in.read()` is a blocking method in Java, your for loop acts as infinite loop. As you suggest you can use `Thread.sleep` inside for loop.  when running the jar with Runtime java API , you are creating additional process in the OS along with your Java Process , but running the jar manually, there is only one java process

Comment: @RameshSubramanian As you say, `read()` is a blocking method; this means the above application should be idle 99% of the time. Since this appears to not be the case (the OP mentions high CPU usage) there must be something preventing `read()` from blocking—hence my guess in my first comment. If `read()` continuously returns `-1` (i.e. end-of-stream) then the thread starts "spinning". Also, the `StartApp` process will exit immediately after launching the `Cycle` application, so the presence of a second process shouldn't matter. Even if it did, I'd expect it to impact RAM, not CPU usage.

Comment: @Slaw You seem to be absolutely right! I connected to the cycle process with remote debug and it continuously returns -1 (or \uFFFF to be more exact), what makes the loop to become infinite.